# Power Automate Desktop - HTTP PUT - creates text file and doesn't upload file to blob storage

Tags: power-automate-desktop

[Picture of INVOKE WEB HTTP PUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiCY9.png)
I am using Power Automate Desktop to log into a website, download a number of xlsx files and then want to upload them to blob storage (Azure). I have other cloud power automate flows that upload to Blob and work just fine. The body becomes .contentBytes

The issue I have is that the actual file is not uploaded but it creates a text file with the name of my .xlsx file and just puts the file path/name in the text file. Rather than uploading the actual file.

I know the URL is OK because it uploads the text file. I am presuming my issue is the body part. But I can't fathom out what I need in there.

Any pointers appreciated

Dave